# Issue with Python Sun get_sunset_time() routine

Tags: python

I don't think this is normal

```
today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()
today_sr < today_ss
False
```

today_sr is `datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 2, 9, 50, tzinfo=tzutc())`
today_ss is `datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 2, 0, 10, tzinfo=tzutc())`

today_ss should be 2022, 5, 3 if it's going to cross over midnight in UTC time.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in this `sun` module you're using.  Maybe it's expecting you to pass another argument and in the absence of that its defaults are nonsensical?  Hard to answer without a link to the module documentation, and a quick google didn't turn it up.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I did a 'sudo pip3 install suntime'. Running on a RasberryPi runing Raspbian Buster. Don't recall where it got the suntime from.

Comment: Running the pip3 install returned:  ```Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: suntime in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from suntime) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil->suntime) (1.12.0)```

Comment: Which returned this if you follow the links: ```Links for suntime
suntime-1.2.1-py3.6.egg
suntime-1.2.1.tar.gz
suntime-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl
suntime-1.2.4.tar.gz
suntime-1.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
suntime-1.2.5-py3.7.egg
suntime-1.2.5.tar.gz```

Answer (score 0):

Samwise got me pointed in the right direction. It's a bug in the routine I'm using

https://github.com/SatAgro/suntime/issues/13

It's been lingering since 2020 so I've fixed it by doing this in my code

```
if today_sr > today_ss:
    today_ss = today_ss + timedelta(days=1)
```